# Action Cable connecting to channel but not receiving data

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I created the following using ActionCable but not able to receive any data that is being broadcasted. It is subscribing to the channel.

This is my DoubleChannel.rb

```
class DoubleChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "doubles_channel_#{params[:id]}"
  end
end
```

This is the "edit" function where i broadcast the message to the channel

```
  def edit
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "doubles_channel_#{params[:id]}", "#{current_user.username} is currently editing the team"
    @double = Double.find(params[:id])
    @competition = @double.competition
    @gameweek = @competition.gameweek
  end
```

this is my doublesFunction.js

```
export function initializeDoubleChannel(doubleId) {
  const cable = createConsumer();
  const channel = cable.subscriptions.create({channel: `DoubleChannel`, id: `${parseInt(doubleId)}`}, {
    connected: function() {
      console.log("Connected to DoubleChannel");
    },
    disconnected: function() {
      console.log("Disconnected from DoubleChannel");
      document.getElementById("channel-status").innerText = "Disconnected from Double Channel";
    },
    received: function(data) {
      console.log("Received data:", data);
      document.getElementById("channel-status").innerText = data;
    }
  });
}
```

and this is the file where i import the initializeDoubleChannel function and call it

```
 import { initializeDoubleChannel } from "./doublesFunctions";
document.addEventListener("turbo:load", (e) => {
  const doubleId = document.querySelector(".double-id").innerText;
  initializeDoubleChannel(doubleId);
}
```

These are the logs when the the edit method is triggered

```
Started GET "/cable" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2024-02-20 16:50:36 +0200
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
DoubleChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
DoubleChannel is streaming from doubles_channel_2
```

Now something weird is happening, when i subscribe to the channel, the data is not received and these are the messages in /cable in the network tab

messages in /cable in the network tab when edit is triggered and subscription to the channel is established (https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYw76.png)

When i refresh the page right before the new page loads, the data is received and i managed to screenshot the messages right before the new page is loaded

messages in /cable network tab right before the new page loads(https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7sCa.png)

As you can see the message is received then, what am i missing?

Comment: you're broadcasting first in your edit action, then when the page loads you're subscribing. you have to subscribe first to receive updates.

Comment: How do i do that? I'm not finding anything online.

Comment: don't subscribe in "turbo:load" event, subscribe once when your application loads then navigate while subscription is active. on refresh you have to just render that the post is being edited by someone else in your template if that's what you're trying to do.